# Critical point for 'hat values' in a normal linear model

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, leverage

I have a normal linear model $y=X \cdot \beta$, where $\beta$ is a $13$-dimensional vector. I want to see if there are any points (I have $287$ data points in total) I can throw out. I want to use hat values. According to my textbooks the rule for critical points is when hat values are above $3 \cdot \frac{k}{n}$. What is $n$ and what is $k$?

Comment: Hint: $n$ and $k$ are two numbers and the first two sentences of your question include two numbers.  But don't do it!  Throwing out such data is *exactly the wrong procedure.*  That's because this criterion identifies the data that potentially have the most impact on the estimates: they're important!  Throwing them out would be like benching all your tall basketball players because they are the best scorers on the team.

Comment: @whuber On the other hand, this might be evidence of outlying observations (in the predictor space) that can seriously damage the non-robust OLS estimator. I cannot speak as to whether deleting them without further investigation is wise but at least for me, high hat values do raise an eyebrow.

Comment: I second @whuber's comment. To that extent, outliers are "part of the game". I would not exclude a point from an analysis unless it was obviously corrupted (eg. negative body weight). High leverage points are always good to check but unless they are obviously wrong I think they are part of the question. There are techniques (eg. IRWLS) to account for "odd" points.